# Find AMI provider username for ec2 instance SSH connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-ami

My ec2 instance doesn't have a key pair. So I am trying to use `EC2 instance connect` on aws console. The problem is that ec2 connect is just a black screen and doens't show any terminal. I already enabled ssh traffic on the security group.

I think it is because I am trying to use the wrong username? The instance `AMI ID` suggest that my platform is `other linux` but I have already tried all the default usernames in the doc and all the other questions I can find on SO. I am not sure about the part where doc says `check with your AMI provider` . What is the step of finding out possible AMI provider username for my ec2 instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Try: **ec2-user**

> For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is **ec2-user**.
>
> For a CentOS AMI, the user name is **centos**.
>
> For a Debian AMI, the user name is **admin**.
>
> For a Fedora AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **fedora**.
>
> For a RHEL AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **root**.
>
> For a SUSE AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **root**.
>
> For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is **ubuntu**.
>
> Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI
> provider.

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html